# How to create a confirmation page linking to the content just created by a user

Tags: nodes

I would like to create a page that that user sees once it has submitted a new piece of content. That page will provide a link to the page that the user has just created, allowing them to share that link through various social networks.

What is the best way to implement something like this? I am not using a webform. The user is allowed to submit an unlimited number of content.

Thanks, Lauren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Rules module http://drupal.org/project/rules, you can build a new rule to redirect (to a new page) the user when create, for example, a node. see examples to Drupal 6 http://drupal.org/node/298483 or Drupal 7 http://drupal.org/node/878712

specifically, I suggest that you review events like 'After saving new content' or/and 'After updating existing content' , then you can launch  task (or add conditions to the task and lauch the task) according your needs. Seems that 'Page redirect' Action can be useful.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I am going to need to become a bit more familiar with php to implement this.